# Setting up concurrent grunt tasks for Cordova project

Tags: cordova, gruntjs

I'm using **Node** with **Grunt** for Cordova hybrid mobile development.

Here is my folder structure

```
myApp
|
|__ platforms
|
|__ www
|
|__ merges
|
|__ src
     |
     |___ app
     |     |__ ios
     |     |    |__ js
     |     |    |    |__ file1.js
     |     |__ android
     |     |    |__ js
     |     |    |   |__ file2.js
     |     |    |   |
     |__ test
     |__ Gruntfile.js
     |__ bower_components
     |__ package.json
```

Here is my Grunt configuration (Gruntfile.js).

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   var config = {
     app: 'app',
     dist: '../www',
     platform: grunt.option('platform');
   };

   require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

   grunt.initConfig({

     config: config,

     jshint: {
       options: {
         jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
       },
       all: [
         '<%= config.app %>/<%= config.platform %>/js/**/*.js'
       ]
     }

     // Others
   });

   grunt.registerTask('jshint-both-platforms', 'Run jshint for single or both platforms', function() {

      // if platform is not passed run jshint for both platforms one by one
      if(config.platform === null) {

        grunt.config.set('platform', 'ios');
        grunt.task.run(['jshint']);

        grunt.config.set('platform', 'android');
        grunt.task.run(['jshint']);

        grunt.config.set('platform', null);

        return;
      }

       // if the platform is passed run jshint for the passed one
       grunt.task.run(['jshint']);
   });

   // others
}
```

If you see the jshint task configuration I've used a single block for both android and ios.

I've a custom task called `jshint-both-platforms` that runs jshint for both platforms if the user don't pass any argument in the command-line or terminal. If you see the custom task I'm running `jshint` task for both platforms one by one sequentially.

How can I run the `jshint` task for both platforms concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

Steps of a grunt task are not concurrent but you can do concurrent jobs at task level by using grunt parallelize:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-parallelize